# Rosetta 2 is not installed on M1

Tags: macos, apple-silicon

The terminal writes about a successful installation, but it is nowhere to be found. And no program can be run through properties.
After such a problem, I tried to find the old program in the store and start the installation like this. But it's strange. Programs that have not been updated for several years are quietly launched.

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
I have read and agree to the terms of the software license agreement. A list of Apple SLAs may be found here: http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/
Type A and press return to agree: a
2021-04-16 17:32:59.495 softwareupdate[2131:42413] Package Authoring Error: 071-08933: Package reference com.apple.pkg.RosettaUpdateAuto is missing installKBytes attribute
Install of Rosetta 2 finished successfully
```

I do not appear in the properties to run through Rosetta
I even downloaded an old Intel program from 5 years ago and it started quietly but Photoshop does not work.
How do I install it so that everything works? help me

Comment: Hi egorskikh - we have this at work, and the error message is almost always a reminder  that you do need to get another app installed. My answers are really rare edge cases, see if you can install a new app to “kick start” the Rosetta process and ensure it’s not already running...

Comment: @nohillside Why do you write that this is a duplicate? That answer didn't solve my problem. Suddenly other people may have it too.

Comment: Without any additional details the questions look the same. Even @bmike‘s answer is applicable to both.

Comment: Without a big edit, nohillside is correct - this should be closed. Keep looking and if you discover more, you can edit your solution in my answer or flag for review once an edit is made. Pointing everyone to the main question is best for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminal is likely lying to you - the error message should say, “Rosetta is already installed” when I see that. If you are sure you don’t have Rosetta and it’s not running and you did get a new Intel app after the error, one lpotential cause of that error is if your network has failed to deliver the update from Apple content delivery network (hard to tell if CDN is overloaded or it’s your network with one try, though).

I would restart the machine and try again. If the error persists, you may need to try a different network or look at reinstalling the OS or troubleshoot further.

A call to Apple support to escalate to engineering may be needed if they don’t fix this “issue” of the installer messaging.

Comment: If after updating the system it will be the same. How long do I have to wait until a new attempt to install it?

Comment: No extra delay in time is needed.  The wait is to try and launch a new Intel app that wasn’t present when you ran the command last @egorskikh